# The way i have implemented a pulsing background color effect on a skeleton in react native is causing the component to infinitely rerender

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, rerender, react-native-animatable

I have implemented a hook in my react native project in order to have all my skeletons for different components in one file as they all use the same animation style

```
const useColorAnimation = () => {
  const { themeColors, accentColor } = useTheme();
  const colorAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [interpolatedColor, setInterpolatedColor] = useState<any>(themeColors?.secondaryBackground);

  const startColorAnimation = () => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(colorAnimation, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 500,
          easing: Easing.linear,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }),
        Animated.timing(colorAnimation, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 500,
          easing: Easing.linear,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }),
      ])
    ).start();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    startColorAnimation();
    colorAnimation.addListener(() => {
      setInterpolatedColor(
        colorAnimation.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [themeColors?.secondaryBackground, themeColors?.primaryBackground],
        })
      );
    });

    return () => {
      colorAnimation.removeAllListeners();
    };
  }, []);

  return { interpolatedColor, themeColors, accentColor };
};

export const DiscoveryCardSkeletons = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const { interpolatedColor, themeColors, accentColor } = useColorAnimation();

  const containerStyleDiscovery: ViewStyle = {
    margin: 10,
    height: 170,
    width: 120,
    marginRight: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
  };

  const containerStyleCommunity: ViewStyle = {
    borderRadius: 16,
    width: 170,
    height: 150,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginBottom: 16,
    backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
  };

  const discussionPostStyle: ViewStyle = {
    width: '100%',
    height: 209,
    backgroundColor: themeColors?.secondaryBackground,
    marginBottom: 10,
  };

  const communityStyle: ViewStyle = {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
    marginBottom: 5,
    borderRadius: 12,
  };

  const playlistsStyle: ViewStyle = {
    height: 130,
    width: 130,
    backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
    marginBottom: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
  };

  const playlistsTitleStyle: ViewStyle = {
    height: 30,
    width: 130,
    backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
    borderRadius: 10,
  };

  const performanceMetricsSkeleton: ViewStyle = {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '46%',
    marginBottom: 12,
    marginHorizontal: '2%',
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    shadowColor: themeColors?.primaryShadow,
    height: 62,
    backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
  };

  const PerformanceMetricsSkeleton = () => <Animated.View style={performanceMetricsSkeleton} />;

  const PlaylistsSkeleton = () => (
    <View>
      <Animated.View style={playlistsStyle} />
      <Animated.View style={playlistsTitleStyle} />
    </View>
  );

  const CardRowSkeleton = () => <Animated.View style={containerStyleDiscovery} />;

  const CardGridSkeleton = () => <Animated.View style={containerStyleCommunity} />;

  const DiscussionPostSkeleton = () => (
    <View style={discussionPostStyle}>
      <View
        style={{
          padding: 12,
          paddingBottom: 0,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          flex: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            borderRadius: 100,
            backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
          }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            paddingHorizontal: 12,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            overflow: 'scroll',
            height: 64,
          }}
        >
          <View>
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                height: 12,
                width: 70,
                borderRadius: 4,
                marginBottom: 10,
                backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
              }}
            />
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                height: 12,
                width: 120,
                borderRadius: 4,
                marginBottom: 10,
                backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
              }}
            />
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                height: 12,
                width: 90,
                borderRadius: 4,
                backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>

        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Animated.View
            style={{
              width: 74,
              height: 36,
              borderRadius: 8,
              backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
            }}
          />

          <ThreeDotsVertical height={30} width={30} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          paddingHorizontal: 12,
          flex: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            width: '60%',
            height: 14,
            borderRadius: 4,
            backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          paddingHorizontal: 12,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          marginBottom: 10,
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              alignItems: 'center',
              flexDirection: 'row',
            }}
          >
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                borderRadius: 100,
                backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
              }}
            />
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                borderRadius: 100,
                backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
                marginLeft: -5,
              }}
            />
          </View>

          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              alignItems: 'center',
              marginLeft: 5,
            }}
          >
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                width: 50,
                height: 14,
                borderRadius: 4,
                backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}
          >
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                width: 8,
                height: 12,
                borderRadius: 2,
                backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
                marginRight: 1,
              }}
            />
            <Typography
              text="Comments •"
              typographyStyle="SmallCopy"
              textColor={themeColors?.secondaryText}
            />
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}
          >
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                width: 8,
                height: 12,
                borderRadius: 2,
                backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
                marginRight: 1,
              }}
            />
            <Typography
              text="Reposts"
              typographyStyle="SmallCopy"
              textColor={themeColors?.secondaryText}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
          paddingTop: 12,
          alignItems: 'center',
          borderTopWidth: 0.2,
          borderTopColor: themeColors?.secondaryText,
          marginBottom: 12,
        }}
      >
        {/* LIKES */}
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            position: 'relative',
          }}
        >
          <LikeIcon color={themeColors?.primaryText} width={24} height={24} />
          <Typography
            text="Like"
            typographyStyle="SmallCopy"
            textColor={themeColors?.secondaryText}
          />
        </View>
        {/* COMMENTS */}

        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ marginRight: 5 }}>
            <CommentBubbleWithDots color={themeColors?.secondaryText} />
          </View>
          <Typography
            text="Comment"
            typographyStyle="SmallCopy"
            textColor={themeColors?.secondaryText}
          />
        </View>

        {/* SHARES */}
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}
        >
          <ShareIcon color={themeColors?.secondaryText} />
          <View style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>
            <Typography
              text="Share"
              typographyStyle="SmallCopy"
              textColor={themeColors?.secondaryText}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  const CommunitiesSkeleton = () => (
    <View
      style={{
        width: 100,
        height: 116,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Animated.View style={communityStyle} />
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            width: 65,
            height: 12,
            borderRadius: 4,
            backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
            marginBottom: 4,
          }}
        />
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            width: 75,
            height: 10,
            backgroundColor: interpolatedColor,
            borderRadius: 4,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  const discoverArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  return {
    PlaylistsSkeleton,
    PerformanceMetricsSkeleton,
    CardRowSkeleton,
    CardGridSkeleton,
    DiscussionPostSkeleton,
    CommunitiesSkeleton,
    discoverArr,
  };
};
```

when using the debug console even though the page doesnt crash or give me an error for an infinite loop if I console log something i notice that the console log is infinite to the speed of the pulsing effect

Comment: Few pointers,
- Make use of useMemo and useCallbacks to reduce unnecessary rendering with required dependencies.
- If possible extract out styling out of DiscoveryCardSkeletons component for code readability.
- After implementing useMemo and useCallbacks, check which piece of code is getting called unnecessarily.